# Python generator for faster processing

Tags: python, mongodb, generator, pymongo

I have a collection `student` having at least 15 million documents. A sample document structure goes like this,

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe400a')",
    "Email":"xxx1@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Blue","Green","Orange","Black"]
    "marks": [{"physics":23,"maths":20,"chemistry":19}]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx2@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Purple","Pink","Magenta","White","Black"]
    "marks": [{"physics":22,"maths":25,"chemistry":19}]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx3@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Red","Yellow","Grey","White","Black"]
    "marks": [{"physics":12,"maths":14,"chemistry":19}]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx4@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Green", "White","Pink"]
    "marks": [{"physics":25,"maths":25,"chemistry":19}]
},
{
    "_id": "ObjectId('5e8baxxxxxe4002')",
    "Email":"xxx5@gmail.com",
    "Favourites": ["Green", "White","Black"]
    "marks": [{"physics":10,"maths":9,"chemistry":19}]
},
.....
....
```

I am looking for a way to write a **Generator** function to calculate total marks for each student document.

My code goes like this.

```
def query():
    r = db.student.aggregate([
          {
          "$project": {
              "Email":1,
              "marks":1,
          }
       }
    ])
    for i in r:
        yield i



def find_total_score(doc):
    total = <code to calculate total by adding marks of physics chemistry and maths>
    doc['total'] = total   #write back the total score for sorting



it = iter(query())
while True:
    try:
        item = next(it)
        find_total_score(item)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Here to complete the entire process it's taking minutes. I am not getting any advantage of using the **Generator** fuction. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What sort of advantage (and compared to **what**) have you expected?

Comment: I need to calculate total score and get them all sorted with less than 10 seconds